# Fonts for ggplot not showing up in rmarkdown html

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, knitr, r-markdown

I have created a plot in ggplot with a specific font (see in code family="Curlz MT"). However, when knitting to html, the font defaults back to original.

```
FarePlot<-ggplot(data = train,aes(x = Survived,y = Fare))+
      geom_boxplot(fill="#56B4E9")+
      ggtitle("Boxplot of Fare by Survival") +
      ylim(c(0,300))+
      theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),
          axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),
          axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          plot.title=element_text(size = 24, family="Curlz MT",face = "bold"),
          text=element_text(size = 18, family="Curlz MT",face="bold"),
          axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", size = 12,face="bold"),
          axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black", size = 12,face="bold"))
```

The font show's up in the R-console. But when I knit to html the font is lost.

How can I get the font to show up when knitting??
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a package to install the different font? You will probably have to include that within the RMarkdown file 'library(package_name)`

Comment: As your first question, you might also want to read this to improve your chances of getting an answer. Providing a minimal working example (MWE) helps a lot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I was missing library(extrafont) in the RMarkdown file.

And thanks for the advice, I will use it for my next question.